# Adding a third specific datatype to read?

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have manated to add an extra specific datatype to read from in my CSV file. Firstly: I choose how many days i want to read from, as you can see in the code, In the "Distribution" column, I only want to look at "main_district", but now i also want to include the column right to the Distribution, named: "Regions", and only look at stations which are in "north" regions, in other words, i want to include the "centrum_middle" variable as you can see in the code.

Here is also a picture of my CSV file:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/NXCQ6.jpg

Based on my code(underneath here), is this possible? Could someone help me with this?

Thank you.

My code works perfectly as it is now, just that i wanto add centrum_middle:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

read_CSV_for_oslo_centrum_middle_days = pd.read_csv('vise_folka/ALL_stations_together.csv', sep=";", encoding ="ISO-8859-1")

day100 = read_CSV_for_oslo_centrum_middle_days[read_CSV_for_oslo_centrum_middle_days['day'] == 100]


main_district = day100[day100['Distribution'] == 'main_district']

centrum_middle = day100[day100['Region' ]== 'north'] # HOW CAN I ADD NORTH REGION AS A THIRD DATATYPE to look at?

top4_visited_stations = main_district.nlargest(4, 'total_visited_cars')

dataframes_for_centrum_middle_stations = read_CSV_for_oslo_centrum_middle_days[read_CSV_for_oslo_centrum_middle_days['name'].isin(top4_visited_stations['name'])]


sns.relplot(x='day', y='avg_queue_length', data=dataframes_for_centrum_middle_stations, hue='name',kind="line")
plt.suptitle("centrum middle")


sns.relplot(x='day', y='avg_total_EV_in_station', data=dataframes_for_centrum_middle_stations, hue='name', kind="line")
plt.suptitle("centrum middle")


plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1):

Solved! I just placed the region variable over the distribution variable, and it works perfectly! Here is the code:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

read_CSV_for_oslo_centrum_middle_days = pd.read_csv('vise_folka/ALL_stations_together.csv', sep=";", encoding ="ISO-8859-1")

day100 = read_CSV_for_oslo_centrum_middle_days[read_CSV_for_oslo_centrum_middle_days['day'] == 100]




west = day100[day100['Region' ]== 'west'] # HOW CAN I ADD NORTH REGION AS A THIRD DATATYPE to look at?

main_district = west[west['Distribution'] == 'main_district']


top4_visited_stations = main_district.nlargest(4, 'total_visited_cars')

dataframes_for_centrum_middle_stations = read_CSV_for_oslo_centrum_middle_days[read_CSV_for_oslo_centrum_middle_days['name'].isin(top4_visited_stations['name'])]


sns.relplot(x='day', y='avg_queue_length', data=dataframes_for_centrum_middle_stations, hue='name',kind="line")
plt.suptitle("west")


sns.relplot(x='day', y='avg_total_EV_in_station', data=dataframes_for_centrum_middle_stations, hue='name', kind="line")
plt.suptitle("west")


plt.show()
```